# Function to avoid repeating code for multiple variables passed to render_template using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a web app that uses yfinance to retrieve stock data, calculate the return over a period and show these outputs to a html template.

The code in my app.py is as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    AAPL = performance(stock_ticker, stock_period, stock_interval)
    GOOG = performance(stock_ticker, stock_period, stock_interval)

    return render_template("index.html", AAPL=AAPL, GOOG=GOOG )
```

performance() is a func that calls the yfinance library and returns an integer value.

I have a list of 30 stocks and wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this other than just repeating the code for every single stock ticker 30 times.

I do need each stock to have its own separate argument I can call in the html template i.e. {{ AAPL }} will be tabled separately to {{ GOOG }}.

I am thinking some sort of for loop iterating over a list of the stock_tickers stored as a list but I'm not sure how to then pass this as an argument to the render_template function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries to achieve the same output

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    stocks={}
    stock_list = ['AAPL','GOOG'...]
    for stock in stock_list:
      stocks[stock] = performance(stock_ticker, stock_period, stock_interval)

    return render_template("index.html",stocks=stocks)
```

and in the template -
`{{ stocks['GOOG'] }}` instead of just `{{ GOOG }}`

Comment: Ok thank you! Wasn't aware I could pass the argument as a dict and then call the dict key inside the html.